# ASP.NET 2.0 add styles dynamically to page in a control

Tags: asp.net, custom-server-controls

I need to add  to the page from within a custom control. I can't use a stylesheet (.css) because I'm using a url(...) and need to resolve the url.

Right now I'm doing:

```
Page.Header.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<style type='text/css'>.xyz { color: blue; }</style>"));
```

But I'm hoping for something a touch more elegant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it's not a bad solution for the problem. If you had an *external stylesheet file*, this piece of code will do the work:

```
HtmlLink cssRef = new HtmlLink();
cssRef.Href = "styles/main.css";
cssRef.Attributes["rel"] = "stylesheet";
cssRef.Attributes["type"] = "text/css";
Page.Header.Controls.Add(cssRef);
```

Another idea is to write **your own ASP.NET ServerControl** "HtmlInlineStyle", so you could call it this way (script tags would be done by your server control):

```
Page.Header.Controls.Add(
   New HtmlInlineStyle(".xyz { width:300px;padding-left:10px }");
```

This [blog entry](http://www.west-wind.com/WebLog/posts/158367.aspx) and the comments show some alternatives (ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock). But in my opinion your solution is okay.

Comment: what is HtmlInlineStyle ? I cant find this class.

Comment: @AntonPutov There is no such class in the .NET framework. It was a suggestion to write your own server control.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way... For example:

Parent ASPX portion:

```
<div id="div1" class="xyz" style="width: 40px; height: 40px;">
    <span>abc</span>
</div>
```

Within the Control:

```
Dim xyzStyle As New Style()
xyzStyle.CssClass = "xyz"
xyzStyle.BackColor = Drawing.Color.LightBlue
Page.Header.StyleSheet.CreateStyleRule(xyzStyle, Nothing, ".xyz")
```

Note that this assumes that the parent ASPX page has the class attribute set for the target control. If not, then you will need to *merge* the style with the control using the MergeStyle method. (This requires that the control be `runat="server"`).

This code renders the following output: (Showing entire source for your convenience)

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Untitled Page </title>
  <style type="text/css">
    .xyz { background-color:LightBlue; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <form name="form1" method="post" action="MyPage.aspx" id="form1">
    <div id="div1" class="xyz" style="width: 40px; height: 40px;">
      <span>abc</span>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah... I'd found the CreateStyleRule but was really annoyed to see that it did not provide a way to provide an extra "styles" string setting. The style attributes I need are mostly not part of the Style() object.

Comment: Hmmm... quite right. I haven't found a way around that problem.

Answer (score 0):

I create my own class and inherit Style, with my own dictionary for attributes that the default Style class does not include. Here is a brief example...

```
                protected override void FillStyleAttributes(CssStyleCollection attributes, IUrlResolutionService urlResolver)
    {
        Dictionary<String, String> _styles = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        _styles.Add("display", "inline-block");
        foreach (String s in _styles.Keys)
        {
            attributes[s] = (String)_styles[s];
        }
        base.FillStyleAttributes(attributes, urlResolver);
    }
```